# How to read complete file if new line character '0A' is part of the file.

Tags: c, file, newline, fgets, fread

I am having a file without any new line character.
It is a continuous file of byte stream.
Say the whole file size is 100Kb. If nth Kb is having '0A', the file read terminates with that (checked with fseek, even-though I give n+10 bytes, it stops with the nth byte) , even-though it is not the actual new line character.
I want to read 100Kb in full stretch. How to do it ?

I am using fgets to read the file.

Comment: If you have a *binary* file, open it in binary mode and don't use text-functions to read it (look at e.g. [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread)).

Comment: "the file read terminates" --> Posting your code in which the read ends would add clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your code.

You cannot use string functions to read binary data, of course they will react as if the input is a string.

Use `fread()`, after allocating a buffer of course.

A typical attempt might be something like:

```
void * load_file(const char *filename, size_t *length)
{
  FILE * const f = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (f == NULL)
    return NULL;
  void *buf = NULL;
  if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) == 0)
  {
    const long size = ftell(f);
    if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET) == 0)
    {
      if ((buf = malloc(size)) != NULL)
      {
        const size_t got = fread(buf, size, 1, f);
        if (got < size)
        {
          free(buf);
          buf = NULL;
        }
        else if (length != NULL)
          *length = size;
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
  return buf;
}
```

The above is not tested, but should serve as a decent outline.

The caller must `free()` the buffer after finishing with it, of course.

Comment: Can these file handlings be used both in windows and Linux environment ?

Comment: @Taala Yes, this is using just C's standard library functionality, should be fine on any platform supporting C. Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it helped you.